# Keeping url fragment in Safari

Tags: url, safari, redirect, url-shortener

I am using a URL shortener service for my long URLs. However, I realized that if a user does not log in my website when clicking the short URL, it redirects the user to log in page. However, when redirecting, it drops the fragment part (keeps only main part and drops everything after #) and the problem only exists on Safari. It works well in Google Chrome. Do you have any suggestions or have any solutions for that?

Thank you

Comment: When you do the redirect, keep the fragment in your server's session storage (or cookie, `localStorage`, etc) then use that on successful login.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that will solve my problem as well and might be a better solution when we compared with mine. Since safari drops the fragment part, I encoded it first and then decoded it if it goes to the login page so I solved my problem. Thank you for your reply.